# What is the qualitative difference between a Michaelis-Menten model and a log-linear model?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

In a book chapter I am reading<sup>1</sup> the authors compare the fit of the relationship between biodiversity and ecosystem function using both a log-linear model and a Michaelis-Menten model.  The authors refer to the Michaelis-Menten model as "saturating" and the log-linear model as non-saturating.

> ...authors of the publications used in [Meta-analysis 1] did not distinguish between non-linear curves that do (Michaelis-Menten) and do not saturate (log-linear).  In [Meta-analysis 2] this distinction could be made and showed that the average R<sup>2</sup> value was 0.690 and 0.682 for the saturating Michaelis-Menten and log-linear relationship, respectively.

My initial investigation into these models (via Wikipedia etc...) appears to show very similar behavior in that they both approach an asymptote with increasing X-values. Furthermore, I am not sure what the authors are referring to with respect to the saturating and non-saturating descriptions because both models appear to saturate.

**My question is, how should I interpret the relationship differently if it fits one of these models versus the other?**

NOTE: I have looked up the models and while I can somewhat understand each, I lack the training to relate them mathematically.  However, I am looking for a non-mathematical comparison of what fitting one or the other would indicate about the relationship they describe.

---

1. Schmidt, B. et al. 2008. "[Consequences of species loss for ecosystem functioning: meta-analyses of data from biodiversity experiments](http://www.zora.uzh.ch/25528/1/Schmid_etal_Naeem09_V.pdf)" in Naeem et al. eds. 2008. Biodiversity, Ecosystem Functioning & Human Wellbeing: an ecological and economic perspective. Oxford University Press.

Comment: It would be better to give the equations. Unless you can give an on-line source for that chapter, you should assume that we can't access it.

Comment: @NickCox the authors do not give the equations. I looked those up on Wikipedia.  I have added the relevant quote from the book chapter however.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that's enough for most people. You're thinning your readership down to quantitative ecologists. There are some here....

Comment: @NickCox that may be.  I thought there may be some fundamental difference between the models that could be expressed fairly easily.

Comment: There probably is. But that depends on seeing what they are. "Loglinear" could mean several things. Michaelis-Menten is parameterised in different ways.

Comment: Which 'log-linear' model are you referring to?

Comment: @Glen_b I have not had a chance to look up the individual papers that the book chapter cites but based on my understanding of the context I am assuming something like like the green line in [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LogLinScale.svg).

Comment: In what sense is $f(x)=x$ 'log-linear'? That seems to go far beyond idiosyncratic use of the term, to border on perverse. At best, that's flat out misleading.

Comment: @Glen_b I guess I am misrepresenting this.  The model that I am expecting is asymptotic. I am assuming that they mean that if you plot y ~ x on a semi-log plot you would get something like that figure but perhaps I am wrong.  It sounds like there is no simple example definition of log-linear.  I guess I will have to go to the cited paper to get more detail.

Comment: "*The model that I am expecting is asymptotic.*" -- okay good, that makes sense, but this is why I don't see what you mean by 'log-linear' (and why I wanted it specified) ... and it certainly rules out $f(x)=x$ even on a log-f scale (the log-function *isn't* asymptotic).

Comment: Looking at Balvanera et al., they don't give a mathematical form for what they mean by 'log-linear' either, but from reading that and Schmidt et al., I don't think their use of 'log-linear' is 'asymptotic' (in the sense of having an upper asymptote at least). I suggest asking someone in the application area for an explicit definition of the various model-forms.

Comment: @Glen_b well that would make sense with their description of non-saturating. So it seems they are considering the "log-linear" model to be non-asymptotic and the Michaelis-Menten model to be asymptotic.    Thanks for all your help with this.